# ¿Se puede generar una copia PNG de un código qr generado con la librería write2DBarcode?

Tags: php, qrcode, tcpdf

Estoy generando códigos qr con la librería de TCPDF usando write2DBarcode en PHP, pero quiero poner mi código dentro de una tabla ya sea una tabla HTML o un MultiCell o Cell pero no lo logro, adjunto el código que estoy usando.

```
$urlQr = "www.google.com"; #URL de codigo QR ;
        $style = array(
            'border' => true,
            'vpadding' => 'auto',
            'hpadding' => 'auto',
            'fgcolor' => array(0, 0, 0),
            'bgcolor' => array(255, 255, 255),
            'module_width' => 1, // width of a single module in points
            'module_height' => 1 // height of a single module in points
        );


$imageQr = $pdf->write2DBarcode($urlQr, 'QRCODE,L', '', '', 40, 40, $style, 'N');


$pdf->MultiCell(55, 40,$imageQr, 1, 'J', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 40, 'T');

$tbl = <<<EOD
 <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" align="center">
 <tr>
    <td><img src="$imageQr"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>$imageQr</td>
 </tr>
</table>
EOD;
```

Eh realizado pruebas con estos fragmentos de código y ninguno funciona, si me pudieran orientar que estoy haciendo mal o si es posible lo que quiero hacer, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Comment: `write2DBarcode` no retorna nada, lo que hace es embeber el qr en tu pdf, por lo cual tu variable nunca tendrá nada.  Debes de encontrar un api u otra forma que te genere el qr para que lo puedas usar como src o base64

Comment: necesitaras crear el QR aparte. Parece que esta libreria cumple esa función https://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/. Luego puedes embeberlo como imagen $pdf->image o usando su path.

Comment: Si quieres hacerlo con TCPDF::write2DBarcode tendras que hacer 2 llamados y mediante los parametros $x y $y posicionarlo en el pdf